# Marketing Cloud Node SDK "No Access Token" error

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, node.js

I'm trying to test SFMC's Node SDK locally, but when i run the index.js file, it returns "No access token" in the CLI. I have my index.js file set up as follows;

```
const ET_Client     = require('sfmc-fuelsdk-node');
const clientId      = "clientId"
const clientSecret  = "clientSecret"
const stack         = 'S7'
origin              = 'https://endpoint.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/'
authOrigin          = 'https://endpoint.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'
soapOrigin          = 'https://endpoint.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/'

const client = new ET_Client(clientId, clientSecret, stack, {origin, authOrigin, soapOrigin});
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

So I believe my issue was two-fold...

1. I believe it's now necessary to use oAuth 2.0 authentication, therefore the following method of retrieving the access token needs to be used

```
const client = new ET_Client(clientId, clientSecret, stack, {origin, authOrigin, soapOrigin, 
authOptions = { authVersion = 2, accountId = <<TARGET_BUSINESS_UNIT>>, scope = <<DATA_ACCESS_PERMISSIONS>>, applicationType = <<public||web||server>>, redirectURI = <<REDIRECT_URL_FOR_PUBLIC/WEB_APP, authorizationCode = <<AUTH_CODE_FOR_PUBLIC/WEB_APP>>}
});
```

2. The code above - [pulled from the node sdk github page](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node) - is actually wrong and returns the following error "SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer". To fix this, I had to modify the way the objects are initialized within the authOptions obj. The following code worked (notice how properties within the object are defined using ':' instead of '=') ;

```
const ET_Client     = require('sfmc-fuelsdk-node');
const clientId      = "clientId"
const clientSecret  = "clientSecret"
const stack         = 'S7'


const origin              = 'https://endpoint.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/'
const authOrigin          = 'https://endpoint.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'
const soapOrigin          = 'https://endpoint.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/'


const client = new ET_Client(
  clientId, 
  clientSecret, 
  stack, 
  {
    origin, 
    authOrigin, 
    soapOrigin, 
    authOptions: { 
      authVersion: 2, 
      accountId: MID, 
      scope: 'data_extensions_read data_extensions_write',
      applicationType: 'server'
    }
  }
);
```